# kmpfit module not in Kapteyn v2.2 module list

Tags: windows, python-2.7, pyodbc, anaconda

I am using Python 2.7 through Anaconda 2.7.8 and need Kapteyn 2.2 to perform Non-linear Least Squares fitting easily (it is probably an alternative to Scipy.optimize.leastsq() for dummies like me!).

After copy-pasting this from a previous post here on Stack Overflow:

> conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/dhirschfeld pyodbc

and then running on my cmd (as I   did not have pyodbc installed I think, because of which maybe the command prompt on my Windows 7 64-bit system was not responding well to ***python setup.py install*** inside the Anaconda directory where I unzipped the Kapteyn .zip file downloaded from University of Groningen website.

But, after the installing pyodbc properly and running ***python setup.py install***, the cmd gave me an error saying **error: command 'C:\Users\windows 7\Anaconda\Scripts\gcc.bat' failed with exit status 1**. Later, when I tried to import kmpfit module (needed for Non-linear least square fitting with Kapteyn), here is the problem:

```
import kapteyn
help(kapteyn)

Help on package kapteyn:

NAME
    kapteyn - Kapteyn package.

FILE
    c:\users\windows 7\anaconda\kapteyn\__init__.py

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    _ni_support
    celestial
    doccer
    filters
    interpolation
    maputils
    mplutil
    positions
    rulers
    shapes
    tabarray
    wcsgrat

DATA
    __all__ = ['celestial', 'wcs', 'wcsgrat', 'tabarray', 'maputils',    'mpl...
    __version__ = '2.2'

VERSION
    2.2
```

As you can see, there is no module named **kmpfit** (or even **wcs**) here. But according to http://www.astro.rug.nl/software/kapteyn/intro.html, these two should be there.

Kindly help. I have never imported any module before. 
Thanks in advance...:-)

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to get this working (on Mac OSX, so you may have to adjust this). My steps were:

1. `$ conda install pyodbc` (didn't need to go through binstar)
2. Download & unarchive the kapteyn package, then navigate to its directory
3. `$ python setup.py install`, which used my OS's C compiler and Anaconda's python, and installed kapteyn to my anaconda distro's site-packages, as it should.
4. Check that `kmpfit.so` is in the kapteyn folder in site-packages, showing that kmpfit installed correctly.
5. `>> from kapteyn import kmpfit` failed, `ImportError: cannot import name kmpfit`. I did some digging and discovered that it was still importing kapteyn from the folder that I downloaded, not from site-packages.
6. Delete the downloaded kapteyn folder, then try again. It worked!